# Xcode: No such module "AsyncSwift"

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

After updating cocoapod for AsyncSwift to 1.6.0, I get "No such module" at:

```
import AsyncSwift
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution is to remove "Swift" from the import, as the module is now called just "Async":

```
import Async
```